# Select/typeahead in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a Lightning Component that, on init, fetches ~1000 values by executing a callout. There are too much values to be displayed on a `<lightning:select>` repeated over rows in a table.

`Table
|- row [1000 values select]
|- row [1000 values select]
|- row [1000 values select]
...`

I would like to use an external library **compliant with LockerService** to use a `select list` (restricted to *n* values) with a *typeahead* behaviour.

I tried with [SelectR](https://github.com/Mobius1/Selectr) without success following the [LockerService documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html)

Any idea, library to propose ?

Comment: Maybe the [Strike](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeLookup) library can help you